# HTTP get method getting empty value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I am using HTTP get method for getting the value from the url, in the url response is getting but for me value is not coming can any one help me. Below is my coding

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gmasa.org/wp-json/posts?type=owl-carousel&filter[Carousel]=speakers&filter[posts_per_page]=-1"]];



NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)requestResponse;
NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];

NSData *requestHandler = [[NSData alloc]init];
requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

 NSLog(@"requestresponce: %@", requestHandler);

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

for me request handler value is getting this like "<>", whats is the problem.

Comment: you should take a look at this library: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking...I think it will help you solve many problems!

Answer (score 0):

Get and analyse a connection error if any and response:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *requestHandler = [[NSData alloc]init];
requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:&error];
NSLog(@"Connection error = %@", error);
NSLog(@"Response = %@", requestResponse);
```

Without this information it is impossible to determine where is a problem - it could be bad connection, bad URL, back-end issue and so on...

Comment: connection error "null" is coming , Responce is coming , nsdata does not coming why